# The application works just a brief moment. Why?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-logcat

The application open and close faster. I saw the code (again) and do not have error. I think that is something related with string,array and image, because when i uncomment Integer[] imgid in Main Activity the app works.

**MainActivity(java):**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {  
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; //DrawerLayout é o menu lateral que expande ao clicar no ícone da sua aplicação ou simplesmente quando você arrasta a tela da esquerda para a direita.
    private ListView mDrawerList; 
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle; // CharSequence como o nome indica é uma sequencia de char, ou seja, texto 
    private CharSequence mTitle; // CharSequence como o nome indica é uma sequencia de char, ou seja, texto 
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private ImageView mIcon;
    private Integer[] random_imgs;

/*    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,
            R.drawable.action_search,
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,
            R.drawable.action_search,
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,
            R.drawable.action_search,
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,

    };*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // responsável por exibir a tela da minha aplicação , baseado nos layouts xml.
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle(); // Gets the title of the frame (String) 
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array); // Pela minha lista de string com o nome dos planetas
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        // ira colocar no list view localizado do drawer_layout, um layout do tipo drawer_list_item, usando os nomes dos planetas
     //   mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       //         R.layout.drawer_list_icon, android.R.id.text2, mPlanetTitles));

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,mPlanetTitles,random_imgs);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Registrar um callback para ser chamado quando um produto neste AdapterView foi clicado .
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
...
```

**CustomListAdapter(java):**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname,
        Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_icon, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

this.context= context;
this.itemname=itemname;
this.imgid=imgid;


}


public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_icon,null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            return rowView;

  }

}
```

**String(xml):**

```
...
  <array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </array>
    ...
```

Here is the logcat of my application.
**Logcat**

```
11-15 12:18:59.282: D/OpenGLRenderer(21513): Enabling debug mode 0
11-15 12:18:59.302: D/dalvikvm(21513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 146K, 18% free 3187K/3852K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-15 12:18:59.302: I/dalvikvm-heap(21513): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.241MB for 1152012-byte allocation
11-15 12:18:59.312: D/dalvikvm(21513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 4312K/4980K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-15 12:18:59.352: D/AndroidRuntime(21513): Shutting down VM
11-15 12:18:59.352: W/dalvikvm(21513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64cb4b20)
11-15 12:18:59.352: D/AndroidRuntime(21513): procName from cmdline: com.examplo.myapp
11-15 12:18:59.352: E/AndroidRuntime(21513): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.examplo.myapp
11-15 12:18:59.352: D/AndroidRuntime(21513): file written successfully with content: com.examplo.myapp StringBuffer : ;com.examplo.myapp
```

Comment: "thread exiting with uncaught exception" try and catch it so you will undertand

Comment: `11-15 12:18:59.352: W/dalvikvm(21513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64cb4b20)`  --- Have a look at it and catch it

Comment: What are you talking?

Comment: The `Integer[] random_imgs` is null because you never initialize it.